# convert array in array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I would like to convert an array like this :

**url : Array**

```
0:"michael"
1:"jason"
```

**url : Array**

```
0:Array
 0:"michael"
1:Array
 0:"jason"
```

I need it for add data to (jquery) datatable ("aaData": exceptions,)

Comment: Sorry it makes no sense what you posted

Comment: So you want to convert an array into an array(of the same length) which has a subarray of the same values?
Unless you want to add objects inside your array, I don't see any point in doing that. But if you want to do, use the map function over the arr and return [data] (assuming data is the function parameter)

Comment: I have an string with this value 
url="michael,jason";
i've splited this values with
var result= url.split(";");
now i have result = ["michael","jason"]
but i need somenthing like result =[["michael"],["jason"]];

I need it to add this information to datatable "aaData"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript the Array is this: `["michael", "jason"]`

This is an Object: `{0: "michael", 1: "jason"}`

To convert Array as you wrote you can use script like this:

```
var a = ["michael", "jason"];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = [a[i]];
}
```

To convert Object as you wrote you can use script like this:

```
var obj = {0: "michael", 1: "jason"};
for (var i in obj) { // here is a difference - using `in` keyword
    obj[i] = [obj[i]];
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vSLD/).

**UPDATE:**

For modern browsers (IE9+, FF1.5+) you can use map method of Array object:

```
var a = ["michael", "jason"];
a = a.map(function(item) {
    return [item];
});
```